# Compare 2 sets of 2 columns in excel with a lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi all I need help with the following formula I have looked up ways to compare different datasets in excel but this particular is a little different to the examples ive seen. Say i have the following data set

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 75 | AB | 75 | Bob |  |
| AC | 56 | AC | 68 | Fre |  |
| AB | 75 | AB | 75 | Jill |  |

I need a formula that compares (AB with CD) and prints out E where F is.

for example the result above would like this this since AB & CD are equal so print the name

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 75 | AB | 75 | Bob | Bob, Jill |
| AC | 56 | AC | 68 | Fre | Fre |
| AB | 75 | AB | 75 | Jill |  |

Comment: What is the relation of column F to the other columns? It's not very clear from your question.

Comment: What would be result for 3rd row? It should same as first row `Bob, Jill`.

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear. the result F should just be a concatenation of any name that matches AB & CD. so @Harun24HR F4  would have the same data as F2

Comment: Row F has no correlation

Comment: @Dritzz If you have `Excel365` then try my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try on below formula.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER($E$1:$E$3,MMULT(($A$1:$B$3=A1:B1)*($C$1:$D$3=C1:D1),TRANSPOSE({1,1}))))
```

[image]